Scraping an Api but not getting the result page I want
glad you look at this question. I really need help...
I used to scrape the site www.britishhorseracing.com for the results from fixtures like
https://www.britishhorseracing.com/racing/results/fixture-results/#!/2024/702
I want the change in distance that is listed for each race, and a little bit further down the road, also the "going" part.
With the help of a nice user here, I managed to find and scrape the api which gave me a result page like
https://api09.horseracing.software/bha/v1/fixtures/2024/702
I used a simple script in scrapy to cycle through the site-numbers I needed, checking them beforehand in my browser for the correct dates
import scrapy
import json


class ApicrawlerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'apicrawler'
    allowed_domains = ['britishhorseracing.com']
    start_urls = ['http://britishhorseracing.com/']
    allowed_domains = ['www.britishhorseracing.com']
    urls = 'https://api09.horseracing.software/bha/v1/fixtures?page='
    start_urls = []
    page_number1 = 4214
    while page_number1 <= 4220:
        page_number = str(page_number1)
        start_urls.append('https://api09.horseracing.software/bha/v1/fixtures?page=' + page_number)
        page_number1 +=1
    print(start_urls)
    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        print(data)
        data2 = data['data']
        for data3 in data2:
            fixtureID = data3['fixtureId']
            fixtureYear = data3['fixtureYear']
            base_url = 'https://api09.horseracing.software/bha/v1/fixtures'
            races_url = f'{base_url}/{fixtureYear}/{fixtureID}/races'
            #going_url = f'{base_url}/{fixtureYear}/{fixtureID}/going'
            yield{
                'url' : races_url
            }

Now the problem:
They updated their site, and now all I get is a blank logo site, no matter what api I try to scrape or access.
I can can still see the different apis being fetched, but I am not able to access them directly anymore.
There is some kind of protection I guess, but this far outweighs my skill in Scrapy and I can not see what is happening there - I guess some kind of cookie or handshake?
I would really appreciate if somebody could point me in the right direction.
P.S.:
I also tried to scrape the webpage by cycling through the pages, but I was not able to get around the !# in the url...

change your allowed_domains value www.britishhorseracing.com to https://www.britishhorseracing.com according to your target API behavior this is the valid origin,

Invalid: Origin: www.britishhorseracing.com
Valid: Origin: https://www.britishhorseracing.com

Sample code with requests:
import requests

for i in range(4214,4220):
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:130.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/130.0",
        "Origin": "https://www.britishhorseracing.com"
    }
    url = f"https://api09.horseracing.software/bha/v1/fixtures?page={i}"
    resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    for data in resp['data']:
        races_url = f"https://api09.horseracing.software/bha/v1/fixtures/{data['fixtureYear']}/{data['fixtureId']}/races"
        if data['abandonedReasonCode'] == 0: #if the value is more than zero that means the race is abandoned and only the logo with 404 Not Found will be returned in your scrapy script
            get_json = requests.get(races_url, headers=headers).json()
            print(f"FIXTURE ID: {data['fixtureId']} ===================== FIXTURE YEAR: {data['fixtureYear']} =====================\n")
            for i in get_json['data']:
                print(f"------------------------\nRACE ID:  {i['raceId']}\nRACE NAME:  {i['raceName']}\nRACE DATE:  {i['raceDate']}\nRACE AMOUNT:  {i['prizeAmount']} {i['prizeCurrency']}\nRACE DISTANCE:  {i['rawDistanceText']}\n")

        else:
            print(f"[ABANDONED-RACE-INFO]: FIXTURE ID: {data['fixtureId']} | FIXTURE YEAR: {data['fixtureYear']} IS ABANDONED\n")

Output:
[ABANDONED-RACE-INFO]: FIXTURE ID: 11672 | FIXTURE YEAR: 2024 IS ABANDONED

FIXTURE ID: 1430 ===================== FIXTURE YEAR: 2024 =====================

------------------------
RACE ID:  57310
RACE NAME:  THE BETFRED 'DOUBLE DELIGHT' NURSERY HANDICAP STAKES (CLASS 4)
RACE DATE:  2024-09-29
RACE AMOUNT:  12000 GBP
RACE DISTANCE:  about SEVEN FURLONGS (7f abt 3yds)

------------------------
RACE ID:  6487
RACE NAME:  THE BETFRED DERBY 'WILD CARD' EBF CONDITIONS STAKES (CLASS 2) (GBB RACE)
RACE DATE:  2024-09-29
RACE AMOUNT:  19000 GBP
RACE DISTANCE:  ONE MILE about 113 YARDS (8f abt 113yds)

------------------------
RACE ID:  57313
RACE NAME:  THE BETFRED 'PICKYOURPUNT' NOVICE STAKES (CLASS 4) (GBB RACE)
RACE DATE:  2024-09-29
RACE AMOUNT:  10000 GBP
RACE DISTANCE:  ONE MILE about TWO FURLONGS (10f abt 17yds)


Thanks! It worked before, so I did not expect the problem to be there.... I changed the "allowed domain" to allowed_domains = ['https://www.britishhorseracing.com'] I still get an empty Json file if I use "scrapy crawl apicrawler -O api.json" - Same if I try to crawl the results like "https://api09.horseracing.software/bha/v1/fixtures/2024/1452/races" - Scrapy only gets the empty page

some races abandoned by your target app that's why you're seeing only a logo with a 404 Not Found  error, eg: try this https://api09.horseracing.software/bha/v1/fixtures/2024/11672/race I have edited my code, hope this will work

Thank you again - request works, scrapy sadly does not - I get a redirect if I use scrapy: 2024-10-18 22:51:51 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://api09.horseracing.software:443/> from <GET http://api09.horseracing.software>
2024-10-18 22:51:51 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://api09.horseracing.software:443/> (referer: None)
2024-10-18 22:51:51 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://api09.horseracing.software:443/> (referer: None)
response  https://api09.horseracing.software:443/
